# Adding padding to an image with imagemagick ONLY if white or transparent background

Tags: imagemagick

Im working on an image gallery application and we need to conditionally add padding around images that have a white or transparent background so they look normal inside the grid on our page.

Basically we need to:

1. Check to see if the image has a white or transparent background
2. If yes, add a 5px transparent border around the image.
3. If no, do nothing.

Is there a way to do this with ImageMagick in one or two lines or do we need to use an additional library?

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines probably sums up all the stuff that follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# By default, do not add border
addborder=0

# Get image geometry to see if IM thinks it has a border
geometry=$(identify -format "%g" "$1")
echo DEBUG: geometry: $geometry

# Ask IM what would happen if we trimmed image
trim=$(convert "$1" -format "%@" info:)
echo DEBUG: trim: $trim

if [ $geometry = $trim ]; then
   echo DEBUG: Image does not have a border
   exit
fi

# Get top-left pixel
topleft=$(convert "$1" -format "%[pixel:s.p{0,0}]" info:)
echo DEBUG: Image has border, border colour is: $topleft

# Decide whether to add border
[ $topleft = "white" ] && addborder=1
[ $topleft = "gray(255)" ] && addborder=1
[ $topleft = "graya(0,0)" ] && addborder=1
[ $topleft = "none"  ] && addborder=1
echo DEBUG:addborder: $addborder

if [ $addborder -eq 1 ]; then
    echo DEBUG: adding border
    convert "$1" -bordercolor none -border 5x5 output.png
fi
```

Other related information and ideas...

You can just use Imageagick's `trim` function to trim any solid or transparent border, like this:

```
convert input.jpg -trim +repage output.jpg
```

If there is no solid border it does nothing. The `+repage` resets the canvas around the picture so it no longer remembers it was part of something bigger.

Or, you can do a whole directory full of images with `mogrify`

```
mogrify -fuzz 15% -trim +repage *.jpg
```

The `fuzz` factor allows there to be slight variations in the border colour whilst still trimming it.

Adding the new border on can be done at the same time with this:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 10% -trim +repage -bordercolor white -border 5x5 output.jpg
```

Or, if you want to do some more detailed processing, you could get the top-left corner pixel and decide what you want to do dependent on its value:

```
convert input.png -format "%[pixel:s.p{0,0}]" info:
```

Let's create a transparent image and check what we get:

```
convert -size 10x10 xc:none input.png
convert input.png -format "%[pixel:s.p{0,0}]" info:

graya(0,0)
```

and a white one:

```
convert -size 10x10 xc:white input.png
convert input.png -format "%[pixel:s.p{0,0}]" info:

gray(255)
```

and a red one:

```
convert -size 10x10 xc:red input.png
convert input.png -format "%[pixel:s.p{0,0}]" info:

red
```